# SPARQL MINUS command not showing correct results

Tags: sparql

I am trying to print all Persons in dbpedia (http://dbpedia.org/sparql) that lack the property "abstract". When I run this code I can see that some persons, for example, Hassan Al-Qazwini in the output has the property abstract. I am doing something wrong?

```
select ?s where {
    ?s a dbo:Person.
    MINUS {?s dbo:abstract ?z}
}
```

Comment: `select ?s where {
    ?s a dbo:Person.
    filter not exists {?s dbo:abstract ?z}
}` does the same but also returns "Hassan Al-Qazwini".

Comment: the reason is simple: DBpedia redirects based on Wikipedia redirects. For example, `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hassan_Al-Qazwini` does indeed not have an abstract, but if you open this URI in a browser you will be redirected to its canonical URI `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Sayed_Hassan_Al-Qazwini` - it was done to allow for alternative URIs identifizing the same resource but having all data just attached to a single RDF resource in the end

Comment: a way to solve this is to check for redirects as well, i.e. all persons the have an abstract or are redirected to a person that has an abstract. For example this might work `select ?s where {

    ?s a dbo:Person.
    minus {?s dbo:wikiPageRedirects?/dbo:abstract ?z}
}`

Comment: I think it worked! Isn't theoretically possible a person without an abstract to be related to a different entity with an abstract and so to not be present in the results? Thanx anyway.

Comment: Is this a different question now? Did you understand my explanation why you got some persons back in your query but in the browser you saw an abstract?

Comment: Yes, I understand it.

Comment: Ok, and what did you mean with your last question? What does not work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that DBpedia redirects based on Wikipedia redirects. For example, `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hassan_Al-Qazwini` does indeed not have an abstract, but if you open this URI in a browser you will be redirected to its canonical URI `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Sayed_Hassan_Al-Qazwini` - it was done to allow for alternative URIs identifizing the same resource but having all data just attached to a single RDF resource in the end.

A way to solve this is to check for redirects as well, i.e. all persons that have an abstract or are redirected to a person that has an abstract. For example this might work:

```
select ?s 
where { ?s a dbo:Person. minus {?s dbo:wikiPageRedirects?/dbo:abstract ?z} }
```